# HtmlUnit driver error

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I just started using HTML unit driver and when trying to run the application I get this error message in Eclipse. Do I miss something in my installation ?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate declared field class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.dnsResolver
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'Gigavoice-PC', ip: '10.19.241.138', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:534)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:508)
at automationFramework.CheckRedirects.main(CheckRedirects.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate declared field class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.dnsResolver
at org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:155)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.readDeclaredField(FieldUtils.java:512)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getField(HttpWebConnection.java:1036)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.createConnectionManager(HttpWebConnection.java:959)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:165)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1351)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1268)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:381)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:303)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:450)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:519)
... 2 more <code>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a wrong version of the Apache httpclient library in your classpath. See here: https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1786/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because of using Httpunitdriver(V2.21) und Selenium(V2.53.0) and have already resolved.
Try to start your node with the Command: "Java -cp **htmlunit-driver-standalone-2.21.jar;selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar** org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher - yourServerOptions"

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using maven, add below dependency in your pom.xml and it would work.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```